# Injest data from Lucene index in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, lucene, spark-streaming, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

Is it possible to injest data from a Lucene Index in Apache Spark in order to computational operations for reporting purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are tools to read Apache Solr index data into Spark RDD objects which you can use in your computation and reporting purposes.

Here is a link for a tool that does this:
https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr

Comment: what i understand is for this i need to convert my existing lucene index into  solr index, i.e. write a schema.xml in solr for the fields in my lucene index and then access it using spark-solr connector.. But actually my lucene index has large number of fields and also they get dynamically added.. So i intend to keep my lucene index as it is and for reporting purpose looking for a solution.. thought spark would be a good option as later it can also facilitate machine learning .. But cant figure out a way to integrate it with lucene..